# add space between 2 strings

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to add `whitespace` between a `.` and `number`.

My exampe as below

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Acranthera sp.01", "Aglaia spectabilis (Miq.) S.S.Jain & Bennet", "Alyxia sp.11"))

df
                                       name1
1                            Acranthera sp.01
2 Aglaia spectabilis (Miq.) S.S.Jain & Bennet
3                                Alyxia sp.11
```

My desired output

```
                                       name1
1                            Acranthera sp. 01
2 Aglaia spectabilis (Miq.) S.S.Jain & Bennet
3                                Alyxia sp. 11
```

So far, I only know to use `str_pad` to add the space. Any sugesstions for this with `tidyverse` and `stringr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutate(
  df, 
  name1 = str_replace(
    name1, 
      "\\.(\\d)", # Match a literal . followed by a digit (capturing group 1)
      ". \\1"  # Replace by a ., space and the content of the first capturing group (the digit following the .)
  )
)
```

Comment: note that `str_replace` is from the `stringr` package

Comment: Which is part of the tidyverse

Comment: sorry guys, my bad i should add `stringr` package

Comment: @RobinGertenbach can you explain abit about the `regex` part please

Comment: I elaborated the regex and substitution a bit, hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

in base R:

```
df$name1 <- gsub("(\\.)([0-9])", "\\1 \\2", df$name1)
```

Comment: thank you so much :D. note this down.